# Div não está aparecendo

Tags: javascript, div

Estou tentando fazer uma div aparecer logo depois da outra, mas quando coloco a função, apenas a primeira desaparece e a segunda não aparece.

```
<script>
    function apareceDiv1(){
 document.getElementById("est").style.display="block";

}
   function mostraHoras(){
    var hora = new Date();

    document.getElementById("segundos").innerHTML = hora.getSeconds();
}
    function apareceDiv2(){
 document.getElementById("est2").style.display="block";
}
    function fechaDiv1(){
        document.getElementById("est").style.display="none";
    }
    function apareceDiv3(){
 document.getElementById("est3").style.display="block";
}
    window.onload = function(){
        var cronometro = document.getElementById("cro");
        var fot = document.getElementById("fotos");
        var tabuada = document.getElementById("tab");

        setInterval(mostraHoras,1000);
        cronometro.onclick = apareceDiv1; mostraHoras;

        fot.onclick = fechaDiv1; apareceDiv2; 
        tabuada.onclick = apareceDiv3;


    }

    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simples, no onclick você está adiquirindo 2 valores erroneamente assim fot.onclick = fechaDiv1; apareceDiv2; isso não funciona, crie uma função onclick fica bem melhor, ele vai ficar esperando receber click, quando receber executa as funções desejadas, do modo que você estava fazendo só iria executar a primeira pois você encerrou com um ";" e olha la se for só isso ainda. Qualquer duvida só falar

assim

```
<script>
    function apareceDiv1(){
 document.getElementById("est").style.display="block";

}
   function mostraHoras(){
    var hora = new Date();

    document.getElementById("segundos").innerHTML = hora.getSeconds();
}
    function apareceDiv2(){
 document.getElementById("est2").style.display="block";
}
    function fechaDiv1(){
        document.getElementById("est").style.display="none";
    }
    function apareceDiv3(){
 document.getElementById("est3").style.display="block";
}
    window.onload = function(){
        var cronometro = document.getElementById("cro");
        var fot = document.getElementById("fotos");
        var tabuada = document.getElementById("tab");

        setInterval(mostraHoras,1000);

 cronometro.addListener('click', function() {
   apareceDiv1();
   mostraHoras();
});

fot.addListener('click', function() {
  fechaDiv1();
  apareceDiv2();
});

  tabuada.addListener('click', function() {
    apareceDiv3();
});

    }

    </script>
```